# What causes IndexOutOfRangeException here?

Tags: c#, list, indexoutofrangeexception

I had a programming exam where at the end, I always had an `IndexOutOfRangeException` for the code below (for the if statement, exactly).

The task was to remove numbers in 21..32 range from the list then print out the new list. `nums` is a `List<int>` with exactly **6** numbers given by the user.

I've been programming for 4 years now and I can't find a single problem :D

Here's the code.

```cs
// nums is a List<int> with exactly 6 elements in it.
List<int> changedNums = new List<int>(nums);
            
for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
    if (changedNums[k] >= 21 && changedNums[k] <= 32)
        changedNums.RemoveAt(k);
```

I didn't put brackets here because it's a one-liner.

Comment: It's pretty dangerous to remove items from an array while you're looping through it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's hard to know *for sure* what's going on without that - in particular, I'd prefer not to accept your assertion than `changedNums` really has 6 elements, without seeing it in the code. I suspect the problem is just that by the time you get to later values of `k`, the list is too short for `changedNums[k]` to be valid because you've removed elements from it... but a [mcve] would help to make that clear.

Comment: If you remove items from a list in a loop like that, you must start from the END and go towards the BEGINNING otherwise your index will be out of range - which is what you're seeing.

Comment: @gunr2171: It's fine to do it *carefully* - in this case, with a loop of `for (int k = 5; k >= 0; k--)`

Comment: Once you remove an element from the list, `changedNums[5]` won't exist anymore, thus you get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Comment: "I didn't put brackets here because it's a one-liner." - I'd strongly recommend putting braces around *every* loop and `if` statement body. It's so easy for a stray semi-colon or bad indentation to cause havoc otherwise.

Comment: I'd also recommend the normal diagnostic approaches - in particular, if you run the code in a debugger and it stops when it hits the exception, I suspect you'll see that `k` is out of range for the list. If you step through the code, you'll see why.

Comment: `var changedNums = nums.Where(n => ! (n>=21 && n<=32)).ToList();`

Comment: "I've been programming for 4 years now and I can't find a single problem :D" In those four years, did you learn any techniques for debugging the code? For example, since the reported error is an out-of-bounds index, I assume you were able to guess that the problem probably has to do with `changedNums[k]`. Can you think of a way to check the value of `k` each time it is used? Can you think of a way to check the length of `changedNums` each time? If you do those checks, can you observe what's going on? When you watch that happen, do you see the problem?

Comment: In your own words, if `changedNums` is - as you say - a list with 6 elements in it (since you copied it from `nums`), and then you do `changedNums.RemoveAt(k);`, what do you think will be the length of `changedNums` after that? After that, is it still permissible to use `5` as an index into `changedNums`? Why or why not? Given that `k` is controlled by a loop `for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)`, will `k` eventually become equal to `5`? Why or why not? Do you see why this causes a problem?

Comment: Separately: in four years of programming, you didn't run into a problem like this before? And it never occurred to you to look for a better way to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: Ok, I would like to answer to some people. First, as I said it was an exam and I had 2 minutes to send it in email, on a slow computer. So, as you can guess, I was really hurrying. It was a really simple exam for me but I rarely do removing random items from a list. I am a partly self learner, these things in school are the easiest for me. I had to use my own algorithms, it wasn't allowed to use LINQ or any built-ins. Unfortunately, I rarely used debugging before (some drawbacks of self learning is that sometimes you don't learn basic and essential things). I will use it from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you modifying the length of the list while iterating. After you deleted at least one item from `changedNums` list, its length is less than the initial 6 (so you get `IndexOutOfRangeException`). Also, once you deleted `k`-th item, you should decrement `k`. I modified your sample code to work as follows:

```
static void Main()
{
    List<int> nums = new List<int>() { 1, 22, 30, 4, 5, 6 };
    List<int> changedNums = new List<int>(nums);
            
    var currentLength = changedNums.Count;
    for (int k = 0; k < currentLength; k++)
    {
        if (changedNums[k] >= 21 && changedNums[k] <= 32)
        {
            changedNums.RemoveAt(k);
            --k;
            --currentLength;
        }
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", changedNums));
}
```

This will print: `1 4 5 6`

**Edit:**

As pointed by @derpirscher and @Jon Skeet in comments, index manipulations can be easily avoided by iterating the array from end to start:

```
List<int> nums = new List<int>() { 1, 22, 30, 4, 5, 6 };
List<int> changedNums = new List<int>(nums);
        
for (int k = changedNums.Count - 1; k >= 0 ; k--)
    if (changedNums[k] >= 21 && changedNums[k] <= 32)
        changedNums.RemoveAt(k);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", changedNums));
```

An even easier solution to your problem can be achieved using LINQ:

```
var changedNums = nums.Where(num => num < 21 || num > 32).ToList();
```

All the solutions will produce the same result `1 4 5 6`

Comment: While you are absolutely right with the first part of your answer, your approach for solving this is rather strange. The WAY EASIER (and therefor typically used) solution would be iterating the array from end to start. Then you won't need to manipulate the current index.

Comment: @derpirscher You are right, I will edit the answer